# how can I simplify this app.component.html in angular 2+?

Tags: angular

I've got a long HTML in my app.component.html that I'd like to make it appear in various conditions, again in the same HTML.

I know this has to do with ng-template and/or ng-container diectives but the articles and official docs I read and tried to understand got me confused even more... They go into too much detail that I cannot wrap my mind around or the examples thy provide does not shed light to my use-case. My use-case is much simpler than those.

Could someone show me how to simplify this sample structure below using one of those directives?

Say you have a div like this

```
<div id='commonHTML'>
   long html here, that you do not want to repeat in your app.component.html
</div>
```

And you want to display that long HTML, when a condition is true.

but I must say that this wont cut it;

```
<div *ngIf="myCondition == 'xyz'">
   <div id='commonHTML'>
      long html here, that you do not want to repeat in your app.component.html
   </div>
</div>
```

this won't cut it for me cause I want that commonHTML to show in different sections on my page... For simplicity purposes, say that I want that HTML to show at the HEADER in condition A, and at the LEFT-SIDEBAR in condition B, and in some other conditions, I want that to appear on the at the footer. So you get the idea..

My question is..

Do you wrap this  in a ng-Template or an ng-Container div? Or do you throw in #templateReference in that div, and somehow, tell angular to use that reference as an insert? If so, what's the syntax?

Comment: I would argue it really depends on the data source, its structure and the logic surrounding it ... could you please share the 'long html' and the way you retrieve it or manipulate it? Basically, you do not want to place texts and images directly hardcoded into the component template -> you load it from some source like and object, json etc. then you inject it into subcomponents and so on ... you use directive for repeating and filtering the data in the template ... but the way you use the directives and components depends on the data you need to display and expected user behavior...

Comment: You always can make a component with your long html (called e.g. longHtml.component) and make <app-long-Html *ngIf="condition"></app-long-Html>

Comment: it's actually a dataTable ( teraData Covalent dataTable ) component. I use it for displaying in search results, in list view and even in detail view. When I copy paste the entire HTML ( that long HTML ) verbatim in those 3 area, it just works. But it would be so much better to create a partial template and insert that reference in those 3 places..

Comment: Eliseo, I appreciate the reply. But I build the entire app using a different approach. I've got one ts file, one html and I build the entire app using 1 single component. ( I created a framework of my own around this structure and it works great, even thought this is not a typical angular way, but I cannot get into the why's of this here.  ).  Can't this problem be solved with ng-template or ng-container? Their name suggest so, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but it does take care of the dying need for the moment and put an end for me to repeat the 100 lines.

Posting it here in case it helps someone...

```
<ng-template #commonHTML>100 lines of HTML here</ng-template>

some html....

<div *ngIf="false;else commonHTML;">
    commonHTML will appear here. 
</div>

some more html ...

<div *ngIf="false;else commonHTML;">
    commonHTML will appear here.
<div>
```

The reason I call this as a not-the-best solution is because of the fact that that I need to use the "false" part.

If anyone can make this solution more handsome, please throw it in. I'll make it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Divide it in different components and then include it on your main app.component.html on the basis of the condition you have ..

like if you have  and  then use the condition in your html to import it ..